# Qt QLineEdit widget to get long text left aligned

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2005, qt4.7

In my Qt application, when the text width in the QLineEdit widget is greater than widget width, it seems QLineEdit can only display the right part of text  (see below). No matter I set the widget to right alignment, or set cursor position to maxTextLength. I will have to click in the QLineEdit text box and hit <kbd>Home</kbd> to see the left part. Is it possible to have the left part displayed by default?

For example:
The text is "`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`" (26 characters), and the QLineEdit width is 11-character.

Right part displayed (pqrstuvwxyz):

```
               [ line edit ]
 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Left part displayed (abcdefghijk):

```
[ line edit ]
 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. Using `void QLineEdit::home(bool mark)`.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can apply stylesheet for QLineEdit with zero cursor position:

```
lineEdit->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { qproperty-cursorPosition: 0; }");
```